# Inner div has 0x0 size even though it has content

Tags: css, html, layout

My `#main` `div` has no `height` or `width` despite having content in it. I want the `#main` `div` to fill 100% of the space between the `header` and the `footer` so it displays the `background-image` for `#main` across the entire page (less the `header` and the `footer`). I haven't been able to get `#main` to fill this entire space dynamically (it should resize when the browser window is resized)... How do I do this?

Html:

```
<body>
  <div id="page">
    <header id="header">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </header>

    <content id="main">
        <h1>Body</h1>
        <p>Text...</p>
    </content>

    <footer id="footer">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </footer>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#page {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#main {
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    background: url('Background.jpg');
}

#header {
    text-align: center;
    background: #595959;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 60px;
}

#header ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 60px;
    width: 19%;
}

#header ul li:hover, #footer ul li:hover {
    background: #696969;
}

#header ul li a, #footer ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #BFBFBF;
}

#footer {
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background: #595959;
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 50px;
}

#footer ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 15%;
}

#footer img {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: set width of main to 100%;

Comment: Did you try my suggestion? See below…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`<content id="main">` is **not** a valid HTML tag](http://htmldog.com/reference/htmltags/), though [you can define it as a block-level element via CSS anyway](http://jsfiddle.net/5Z3ZP/).

I'd recommend you instead just change it to read

```
<div id="main">
    ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css…

```
html, body { height: 100% }
```

… and things should work.

See http://codepen.io/zitrusfrisch/pen/hDHrm

And, yeah, you should fix your HTML as `<content>` is not a valid element. See pen for valid solution.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this code:

```css
#main {
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    background: url('Background.jpg');
}
```

Use this on `body`

```css
body {
    background: url('Background.jpg');
}
#main {
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```